# In Testcafe , I'm not not able to click on button using selector but i'm able to click on button using selenium with same selector

Tags: testing, automated-tests, selector, e2e-testing, testcafe

Below the selector I used and click method

```
    const SubmitButton = Selector('#Login-LoginScreen-LoginDV-submit > div');
    // selector used 
.click(SubmitButton)
    
    //tried this as well
    //.pressKey('enter')
    //.doubleClick(SubmitButton)
```

Comment: You should use the test controller's method `click()` like so `await t.click(SubmitButton)`. I suppose you did this even though your code differs. Then, what does "not able to click" really mean? Does it timeout? Do you get any error?

Comment: import { Selector , t} from 'testcafe';

fixture("Claim Center Home Page").
page(
  ""
);
       const SubmitButton = Selector('#Login-LoginScreen-LoginDV-submit > div').withText('Log In');


test('User can log in to their account', async t => {

  await t
   
  
    .setNativeDialogHandler(() => true)
    .click(SubmitButton)
  
//    .click('#gw-customer--logo')

     });

Comment: Above is actual code I'm using and the test case is getting passed as well. I'm confused it is not clicking and getting passed !!?

Comment: The info you sent is insufficient to find the cause of the problem. Could you please share the tested page's markup or a link to your website?

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Visual Selector Debugger](https://testcafe.io/documentation/404288/guides/intermediate-guides/visual-selector-debugger). This function allows you to debug an existing selector (you can find the element it matches directly in the browser) and create a new selector for the selected element.